# Matrix vs. loop for discretization of PDE

Tags: python, julia, sparse-matrix

I am experimenting with using diffeqpy to solve a PDE by discretization of the spacial dimension, while I treat the time dimension as a set of ordinary differential equations.  I managed to solve a very simple problem using a for loop.  However, when I try to use matrixes, to scale the problem up, the solver provides incorrect answers.

The following piece of code works:

```
from diffeqpy import de
import numpy as np

def f(du,u,p,t):
    #define shape of matrix
    s = (6,7)
    cc = np.matrix((np.zeros(s)))
              
    for j in range(0,6):
        for i in range(0,6):
            if (j == i):
                cc[j,i] = -1.0
                cc[j,i+1] = 1.0      
        
    for j in range(0,6):
        du[j] = cc[j,0]*u[0] + cc[j,1]*u[1] + cc[j,2]*u[2] + cc[j,3]*u[3] + cc[j,4]*u[4] + cc[j,5]*u[5] + cc[j,6]*u[6]

u0 = [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

tspan = (0., 20.)
prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = de.solve(prob)
```

This codes is similar to the following piece of code that also works:

```
from diffeqpy import de

def f(du,u,p,t):
    du[0] = -u[0]+u[1]
    du[1] = -u[1]+u[2]  
    du[2] = -u[2]+u[3]
    du[3] = -u[3]+u[4]
    du[4] = -u[4]+u[5]
    du[5] = -u[5]+u[6]
     
u0 = [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

tspan = (0., 20.)
prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = de.solve(prob)
```

However, when I try and use a matrix operation, the problem just does not solve correctly.  I don't have a background in computer science.  However, I would like to learn more.  Why is the following piece of code not working? Has it got to do with mutable vs. immutable object?  How can I utilize a matrix to make this problem scale to bigger discretisation steps?

```
from diffeqpy import de
import numpy as np

def f(du,u,p,t):
    #define shape of matrix
    
    s = (6,7)
    cc = np.matrix((np.zeros(s)))       
       
    for j in range(0,6):
        for i in range(0,6):
            if (j == i):
                cc[j,i] = -1.0
                cc[j,i+1] = 1.0     
   
    
    x = np.matrix(u).T
 
    du = (cc*x).T

u0 = [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

tspan = (0., 20.)
prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = de.solve(prob)
```

I would appreciate any guidance on this problem.

Comment: Don't just say 'does not work'.  Show actual error (with traceback).

Comment: `diffeqpy` is a lightly used (compared to `numpy`) package. It doesn't even have a tag.  And why the `sparse-matrix` tag.  Using `np.matrix` these days is discouraged; but whether it's part of your problem I don't know.  And if we can't run this code (without finding `diffeqpy`) we can't help you debug this.

Comment: There is no error in the code.  The codes runs.  However, it does not change the initial conditions of the problem. Thus "u" stay unchanged when I use the matrix multiplying.

Comment: The working `f` don't return a value, so they must depend on in-place modification of the `du` argument.  Your matrix version has a `du=...`, which breaks the link with the argument `du`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from diffeqpy import de
import numpy as np

def f(u,p,t):
    #define shape of matrix
    
    s = (6,6)
    cc = np.matrix((np.zeros(s)))       
       
    for j in range(0,6):
        for i in range(0,5):
            if (j == i):
                cc[j,i] = -1.0
                cc[j,i+1] = 1.0
    cc[-1,-1] = -1.0
                
    x = (np.matrix(u).T)
    
    du = (list(((cc*x).T).flat))
    
    return du

u0 = [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1]

tspan = (0., 20.)
prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = de.solve(prob)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing in-place modification, use the 3-argument form:

```
from diffeqpy import de
import numpy as np

def f(u,p,t):
    #define shape of matrix
    
    s = (6,7)
    cc = np.matrix((np.zeros(s)))       
       
    for j in range(0,6):
        for i in range(0,6):
            if (j == i):
                cc[j,i] = -1.0
                cc[j,i+1] = 1.0     
   
    
    x = np.matrix(u).T
 
    du = (cc*x).T

u0 = [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

tspan = (0., 20.)
prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = de.solve(prob)
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, without this guidance I wouldn't have been able to get it to work.  I only had to add a "return du" at the bottom of the function and turn the 2D du matrix into a 1D matrix.  I have posted the code that works below.